# Is there a way to print / draw a circuit on to clothing?

Tags: conductive, thread, clothing

I'm looking for an alternative to conductive thread (since I lack some sewing skills).  I have seen silver conductive pens but I'm wondering if they could be used for clothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe conductive glue will work on fabric. It is definitely cheaper than the CirquitWriter pen so if it doesn't work, there's not much harm :) "[Wire Glue](http://www.wireglue.us/)" is being sold in the US but you can also try to make your own by mixing graphite and glue. There is an [instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Conductive-Glue-and-Glue-a-Circuit/) that explains the process.

Answer (score 6):

See http://www.plusea.at/ for all kinds of wearable electronics.  [Gluing strips of conductive fabric](http://www.flickr.com/photos/plusea/4050956299/in/set-72157615409091847/) is probably better than [conductive glue](http://www.flickr.com/photos/plusea/4107731597/in/set-72157622299881137/).

[How To Get What You Want](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/) by the same people has more details:

- [Traces](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?cat=38)
- [Conductive materials](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?cat=24)

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Xerox has [just announced](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2009/10/27/xerox-develops-silver-ink-for-wearable-or-throwaway-electronics/) a silver ink for wearable and throwaway electronics. I think it's a bit early to use in your projects. The Silver Pen is an interesting idea. I don't know if it'll work!

Answer (score 3):

The Arduino Lilypad is a microcontroller board designed for wearables and e-textiles. Google this one and you will find tutorials and details. Also here is a good book about making electronics click with clothes:

[Open Softwear 2nd Edition](http://softwear.cc/)  ISBN: 978-91-97-95540-9

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how practical this would be, but screenprinting might be an option. Using a screen with a coarse mesh you can print with silver paint. You would need to do a test to make sure the paint is conducting in the way you expect. I have some [articles and notes on my blog pages](http://mintmedia.co.nz/Category:Screenprinting) that might help.

Screenprinting has the advantage that you can quickly make many prints of your circuit or make t-shirts to promote your event/exhibition/party.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a source for all sorts of conductive paints. http://www.lessemf.com/paint.html
Some of them would probably work for painting directly on fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative to conductive thread: wire.

wire-wrap wire (30 AWG) or magnet wire is pretty lightweight and flexible, although constant flexing will eventually make it break.

stranded wire is a bit thicker and heavier, but it will survive flexing longer.

I imagine you would lay it out in a sort of zig-zag or sinewave curve, gluing the midpoints, so that there's a bit of slack between each glue spot to allow the fabric to stretch a little.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the conductivity you need, there might be a solution with fabric made for clothing worn in ESD-protected areas. They contain conductive fibers to discharge static electricity. They do not necessary have a very low resistance, but might be conductive enough to sport some signal path.

You could buy such a fabric which has a conductive thread every cm horizontally and vertically. Then you can cut those threads at specific points so that it builds a kind of schematic.

A different problem is, how you can connect the threads to other circuit elements. I think conductive epoxy used in small drops might do the trick.