# Conductive Fabric

Tags: conductive, fabric

Does anyone know of a maker of Conductive Fabric?

Comment: Shopping questions are a no-no here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying my answer from [Is there a way to print / draw a circuit on to clothing?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/184/is-there-a-way-to-print-draw-a-circuit-on-to-clothing)

See http://www.plusea.at/ for all kinds of wearable electronics, including conductive fabric, thread, etc.

[How To Get What You Want](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/) by the same people has more details:

- [Traces](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?cat=38)
- [Conductive materials](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?cat=24)

  - [Conductive fabrics](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?p=376)

[image][image]

Answer (score 5):

1. [Less EMF](http://www.lessemf.com/fabric.html) has the largest selection in the States
2. [Eeonyx](http://eeonyx.com/) sells a range of high performance materials that you can order to spec.
3. [Fine Silver Products](http://www.fine-silver-productsnet.com/) sells silver-doped fabrics
4. [How To Get What You Want](http://www.kobakant.at/DIY/?p=376) gives a good overview of the known conductive fabric merchants
5. [Fashioning Technology blog](http://fashioningtechnology.ning.com/) should give you some inspiration

A trip to the store with a multi-meter can be enlightening. Various commonly available tapes, fabrics, gels, packages etc. are conductive.

Answer (score 3):

Becky Stern sells conductive thread... perhaps you could sew that in to your fabric?

http://sternlab.org/store/

Answer (score 1):

The [Scientific Wire Co.](http://wires.co.uk/) sells knitted copper wire.

Answer (score 1):

Sparkfun are now selling [conductive fabric](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9770)